# What is the escape sequence in Google query language?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-visualization, escaping, google-query-language

```
=QUERY(,"SELECT 'I ask ""What's the escape sequence?""' ")
        "       '      "     '                      " ' "
```

#### Expected output:

```
I ask "What's the escape sequence?"
```

- `"` Double quote was used for the whole query string
- `'` Single quote was used as boundary/delimiter  for the argument to `SELECT`.
- `""`  Double Double quotes was used inside the argument to `SELECT` statement.

#### Actual output:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " &lt;&gt; "s at line 1, column 21
Was expecting one of:
```

```
&lt;EOF &gt;
"where"...
"group"
"pivot"
"order"...
.
.
.
```

> (Column 21 is  the inner single quote ' after "What" )

#### Things I've done:

- [Search](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) the official documentation=> Nothing there
- Replace all single quotes`'`  other than the delimiter `'` with double single quotes `''`=>`=QUERY(,"SELECT 'I ask ""What''s the escape sequence?""' ")`=>Same error
- Interchange all single quotes`'` and double quotes `"` inside the query string=>`=QUERY(,"SELECT ""I ask 'What""s the escape sequence?'"" ")` as well as `=QUERY(,"SELECT ""I ask 'What""""s the escape sequence?'"" ")`=>Same error at col21

**EDIT:**

I'm NOT looking for a workaround(outside Google query language). As the title states, I want to know whether there is a escape sequence that's accepted by Google-query-language. JavaScript uses `\` as escape sequence like `\'`. Mysql uses two single quotes `''` instead of one `'` as a escape sequence. Although Google sheets is the preferred platform, if a escape sequence is accepted in JavaScript+google-vizualization(which uses the same query language) or any platform that uses Google query language v0.7, The answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is in **`What's`** and here is the solution:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(QUERY( ,
 "select 'I ask ""What♠s the escape sequence?""'", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0), "♠", "'")
```

[image: 0]

---

or change the straight single quote for tilted like:

```
=QUERY(QUERY( ,
 "select 'I ask ""What`s the escape sequence?""'", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(QUERY( ,"select ""I ask ''What's the escape sequence?''""", 0), "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I know that the issue is in single quote. That's exactly why the question is titled What is the escape sequence. Edited my question to clarify what I meant. I'm not looking for a workaround. I want the single quote and the double quote and I want any workaround to be inside  the query itself.

Comment: @TheMaster not so sure there is an escaping - never encountered any, but looking forward to it if anyone comes with it...

Comment: `not so sure there is an escaping` In fact , the double double quote `""` for a single double quote `"` is a escape sequence. If we use a single double quote like this,  `QUERY(,"SELECT 'I ask "What's the escape sequence?"' ")` the query string will fail. `looking forward to it if anyone comes with it` I was hoping the same. If anyone can come up with that sequence, I'd be happy to offer a bounty too.

Comment: @TheMaster looks like combined escaping is not supported. its either escaping for double quote or for single quote: `=QUERY(QUERY( ,"select ""I ask What's the escape sequence?""", 0), "offset 1", 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to double the single quotes:

```
=QUERY(, "SELECT 'I ask ""What''s the escape sequence?""' ")
```

I don't know if your query interface requires doubling the double quotes.  A backslash is also commonly used:

```
=QUERY(, "SELECT 'I ask \"What''s the escape sequence?\"' ")
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure doubling the single quotes didn't work as said in point 2. My formula in point2 is exactly the same as yours. You can easily test this [here](https://sheets.new) (official new sheets link)> Just type in A1 > this formula.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this support question](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0ZGTaYDIpigg/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/docs/ZGTaYDIpigg), there might not be a good way to do that, other than using a placeholder character and wrap the query function in a `substitute()` function... or to find a workaround that doesn't require to use `query()`, I guess...